# Most efficient way to join two dictionaries and group them by different key and sum up values

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, list, dictionary, for-loop

Currently I am struggling with case that needs from me to join dictionaries ,then group them by different key and finally sum up values. And to be honest I can't find efficient way to do that without iterating few times over my dictionaries. I will explain quickly how my steps look like.

1. I am querying mongodb for given collection and I am returning list of dictionaries in format

```
# Each document has unique _id

results = [{"_id": "111111111111111111111111", "countryCode": "SG"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111112", "countryCode": "SG"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111113", "countryCode": "CN"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111114", "countryCode": "SG"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111115", "countryCode": "SG"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111116", "countryCode": "DE"}]
```

I am doing this with pagination, so I am returning from query in a lazy way chunks of 1000 documents size. (list of documents)

2. For each `_id` from list above I query another storage with aggregation query in which I basically make a grouping and I count some statistics for given `_id`. So here is example of my query:

```
def query_events(collection_id: str, ids: list):
    q = [
        {"$match": {"recordId": {"$in": ids}}},
        {"$unwind": {...}},
        {"$project": {...}},
        {"$group": {...}},
        {"$group": {...}}
    ]
    coll = db.get_collection(collection_id)
    return list(coll.aggregate(q))
```

3. With the results of this query I do some processing and I convert it to one big dictionary. In format like below:

```
changes = {
"111111111111111111111111": {"ADDED": 15, "MODIFIED" : 12, "REMOVED" : 3}, 
"111111111111111111111112": {"ADDED": 12, "REMOVED" : 12}, 
"111111111111111111111113": {"ADDED": 3, "MODIFIED" : 3, "REMOVED" : 55}, 
"111111111111111111111114": {}, 
"111111111111111111111115": {"ADDED": 10, "MODIFIED" : 15, "REMOVED" : 43}, 
"111111111111111111111116": {"ADDED": 44, "MODIFIED" : 52, "REMOVED" : 11}, 
}
```

And now my goal is to merge this dictionary (point 3.) with list of dictionaries from (point 1.) in the way that I will have information about country in my dictionary (point 3.). I tried something like this:

```
for item in results:
    _id = item['_id']
    if _id in changes:
        del item['_id']
        changes[_id].update(item)
```

After that I get something like this:

```
changes = {
"111111111111111111111111": {"ADDED": 15, "MODIFIED" : 12, "REMOVED" : 3, "countryCode": "SG"}, 
"111111111111111111111112": {"ADDED": 12, "REMOVED" : 12, "countryCode": "SG"}, 
"111111111111111111111113": {"ADDED": 3, "MODIFIED" : 3, "REMOVED" : 55, "countryCode": "CN"}, 
"111111111111111111111114": {"countryCode": "SG"}, 
"111111111111111111111115": {"ADDED": 10, "MODIFIED" : 15, "REMOVED" : 43, "countryCode": "SG"}, 
"111111111111111111111116": {"ADDED": 44, "MODIFIED" : 52, "REMOVED" : 11, "countryCode": "DE"}, 
}
```

But now what I need to receive as my final results is an dictionary or list of dictionaries where my key will be countryCode, and value will be dictionary with `{'ADDED': <sum>, 'MODIFIED" : <sum>, "REMOVED" : <sum>}`

Like here:

```
# as a dict

{
"DE" : {"ADDED" : 44, "MODIFIED" : 52 , "REMOVED" :11},
"SG" : {"ADDED" : 37, "MODIFIED" : 27 , "REMOVED" :58},
"CN" : {"ADDED": 3, 'MODIFIED" : 3, "REMOVED" : 55},
}
```

For now my only idea is to somehow iterate over my dictionary and try to add country do new dictionary as a key if it not exists and `{"ADDED" : 44, "MODIFIED" : 52 , "REMOVED" :11}` as a value of this key, but in case if country already exists in dict then iterate over record values and for each category `(ADDED, REMOVED, MODIFIED)` sum up values. But I think it can be not efficient. I have to take data from collection which has more then 10 Milion records, so it probably will be very slow if I will iterate over those dictionaries.

My aproach (probably not efficient):

```
results = [{"_id": "111111111111111111111111", "countryCode": "SG"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111112", "countryCode": "SG"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111113", "countryCode": "CN"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111114", "countryCode": "SG"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111115", "countryCode": "SG"}, 
{"_id": "111111111111111111111116", "countryCode": "DE"}]

changes = {
"111111111111111111111111": {"ADDED": 15, "MODIFIED" : 12, "REMOVED" : 3}, 
"111111111111111111111112": {"ADDED": 12, "REMOVED" : 12}, 
"111111111111111111111113": {"ADDED": 3, "MODIFIED" : 3, "REMOVED" : 55}, 
"111111111111111111111114": {}, 
"111111111111111111111115": {"ADDED": 10, "MODIFIED" : 15, "REMOVED" : 43}, 
"111111111111111111111116": {"ADDED": 44, "MODIFIED" : 52, "REMOVED" : 11}, 
}

# Update dict with countryCode

for item in results:
    _id = item.pop('_id')
    if _id in changes:
        changes[_id].update(item)


# Now changes looks like:

changes = {
"111111111111111111111111": {"ADDED": 15, "MODIFIED" : 12, "REMOVED" : 3, "countryCode": "SG"}, 
"111111111111111111111112": {"ADDED": 12, "REMOVED" : 12, "countryCode": "SG"}, 
"111111111111111111111113": {"ADDED": 3, "MODIFIED" : 3, "REMOVED" : 55, "countryCode": "CN"}, 
"111111111111111111111114": {"countryCode": "SG"}, 
"111111111111111111111115": {"ADDED": 10, "MODIFIED" : 15, "REMOVED" : 43, "countryCode": "SG"}, 
"111111111111111111111116": {"ADDED": 44, "MODIFIED" : 52, "REMOVED" : 11, "countryCode": "DE"}, 
}


# Last step group data by country and sum-up statistics

final_results = {}

for k, v in changes.items():
    country = v.pop("countryCode", "UNKNOWN")
    if country not in final_results:
        final_results[country] = v
    else:
        for ck, cv in v.items():
            if ck not in final_results[country]:
                final_results[country][ck] = cv
            else:
                final_results[country][ck] += cv


# After this for loop I achieved my results:

final_results = {
"DE" : {"ADDED" : 44, "MODIFIED" : 52 , "REMOVED" :11},
"SG" : {"ADDED" : 37, "MODIFIED" : 27 , "REMOVED" :58},
"CN" : {"ADDED": 3, 'MODIFIED" : 3, "REMOVED" : 55},
}
```

Even if I achieved my results, maybe there is better way to do that.

Do you have any idea how I can achieve my goal - to have sumed-up value at country level for each of one category `(ADDED, REMOVED, MODIFIED)` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) + [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) + [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) + [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add):

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
from functools import reduce
from collections import Counter
import operator as op
import itertools as it
```

2. We are going to change the structure of `results` list, having as key the `_id`

```
results = [{r['_id']: {'countryCode': value} for value in r.values()} for r in results]
```

3. Then, we are going to update `changes` dictionary with the `results` list.

```
for index, key in enumerate(changes.keys()):
    changes[key].update(results[index][key])
```

4. Finally, we are going to use `itertools.groupby` in order to group our data based on the `countryCode` key. `aggregations` is a list of `Counters`, for example: `[Counter({'ADDED': 3, 'MODIFIED': 3, 'REMOVED': 1, 'countryCode': 'DE'}), Counter(...)]`. We are going to use `reduce` in order to sum each Counter object in the list above.

```
output = dict()
for g, iter in it.groupby(changes.values(), lambda d: d['countryCode']):
  aggregations = [Counter(i) for i in iter]
  for agg in aggregations:
    del agg['countryCode']
  aggregations = reduce(op.add, aggregations)
  output[g] = aggregations if g not in output.keys() else reduce(op.add, [output[g], aggregations])

# If you don't make this, then you'll get {'CN': Counter({...}), ...}
output = {key: dict(value) for key, value in output.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'CN': {'ADDED': 3, 'MODIFIED': 3, 'REMOVED': 55},
 'DE': {'ADDED': 44, 'MODIFIED': 52, 'REMOVED': 11},
 'SG': {'ADDED': 37, 'MODIFIED': 27, 'REMOVED': 58}}
```